# Able to auto-login but some commands in text file are not executing in SSH

Tags: batch, putty

How can I access the password for mvslogin.sh in putty. I am using below commands in a batch file:

`C:\Users\pathaanj\Desktop\plink.exe -ssh tpcvld01 -l lz87t1 -pw automate_12 < C:\Users\pathaanj\Desktop\file.txt`

This command is working fine, I have no issues with this command. The problem is with the below mentioned `file.txt`, which I am using for execution of some more commands which are mentioned below. The `file.txt` contains:

```
mvslogin.sh
lz87t1
mother01 (password)
mother01 (password)
automate_12 (password)
```

Here `mvslogin.sh` is a command after execution of command it will ask for ID and 3 consecutive password mentioned above but the problem is, it is not taking ID and password from that text file. So until now, it is connected and runs first two commands but then it is not taking the password `mother01` for the further processing. Here is a snap of that.

```
C:\Users\pathaanj\Desktop>C:\Users\pathaanj\Desktop\plink.exe -ssh tpcvld01.sys.
eds.com -l lz86w4 -pw Jaimataki_12  0<C:\Users\pathaanj\Desktop\file.txt
Using username "lz86w4".
Last login: Thu Apr 25 21:03:09 2013 from 204.26.146.251
lz86w4@tpcvld01:~> mvslogin.sh
←[H←[2JEnter zOS/MVS (MVS2) id:**
```

(Here it should take id from text file but it is not taking)

```
**
```

NOTE: Password is not visible when entered.

```
Enter zOS/MVS (MVS2) password:
```

Can anybody suggest what the problem and solution is?